# Returning parse error from templates when map lookup fails

Tags: go

I have a series of templates that use generic `map[string]string` value in them. Something like

```
 <h1> You sent in {{.Field1}} and {{.Field2}} </h1>
```

The payload will be: `{"Field1": "Value1", "Field2": "Value2"}`

Called as: `err := tmpl.Execute(w, data);  // data is map[string]string and was decoded from the payload`

I cannot convert `data` to a `struct` as the templates and payload are determined at runtime. These templates are created by business users and I don't want to create a type for each template and change the backend every time there is a new template. Hence the desire to keep the `map[string]string` like solution.

The issue with the above design is that when a field used in the template is not passed in at runtime. When I execute the template, the missing fields return an empty string in the template. I would like to return an error if that happens.

So, I would like to know if there a way to make the template return a parse error when the map-lookup fails?  Or is there a way to pass generic `struct` values with runtime error checking to a template that allows for dynamic payloads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ["missingkey=error"](https://godoc.org/html/template#Template.Option) option.

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("").Option("missingkey=error").Parse(
      `<h1> You sent in {{.Field1}} and {{.Field2}} </h1>`))
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/eiHqauBHnh)

Comment: Tnanks @KarrotKake. I am getting this error when I try to use `Option`: ` "html/template".New("").Option undefined (type *"html/template".Template has no field or method Option)`  I am using `go1.6` (appengine -- not sure if it makes any difference)

Comment: @Ecognium Go 1.6 includes the template `Option` method. See the example linked from the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I think the issue seems to be on the appengine runtime side. I will probably have to switch to their managed vm to make this work. I never knew about `Option` so thank you for showing how to handle this.

Comment: Just for other people's benefit. Upgrading the latest appengine SDK fixed the problem (it was pointing to `go1.4.2`. before)